Greengrass not unzipping s3 artifact
I'm trying the AWS greengrass to manage my devices. The bellow is my receipe.
{
  "RecipeFormatVersion": "2020-01-25",
  "ComponentName": "com.test.setup",
  "ComponentVersion": "1.0.10",
  "ComponentType": "aws.greengrass.generic",
  "ComponentDescription": "This version is for testing the decompress",
  "ComponentPublisher": "Me",
  "ComponentConfiguration": {
    "DefaultConfiguration": {
      "Message": "world"
    }
  },
  "Manifests": [
    {
      "Platform": {
        "os": "linux"
      },
      "Name": "Linux",
      "Lifecycle": {
        "run": "python3 {artifacts:decompressedPath}/compress-test/test.py"
      },
      "Artifacts": [
        {
          "Uri": "s3://path/to/compress-test.zip",
          "Digest": "xxxx",
          "Algorithm": "SHA-256",
          "Unarchive": "ZIP",
          "Permission": {
            "Read": "ALL",
            "Execute": "ALL"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Lifecycle": {}
}

After deploying it, I can see there is a new folder named "com.test.setup" at "/greengrass/v2/packages/artifacts-unarchived/com.test.setup", but this folder is empty. I'm not sure what went wrong, I've read the document and this receipe should be correct but no idea why it is not decompressing the artifact to that folder. Any help will be appreciated
Thanks.

From your recipe remove the digest, you don't need it, it will be calculated by Greengrass. If you want to understand what's happening, you have to look at the greengrass.log file in /greengrass/v2/logs/greengrass.log (maybe wrong permission?)
